# How can I fix screen shift bug on virtualbox windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I  am trying to use windows 10 virtual machine on VirtualBox on the Ubuntu host machine. But the graphics are too buggy like the following:
https://streamable.com/s2rof

Every application(visual studio,notepad++) behave like this, chrome browser is just an example

I have done some research and have tried the followings:

- Guest Additions Installed
- RAM Memory Checked 4096 MB
- Display Memory Checked - Maximum Size - 256 MB
- 2D and 3D Acceleration Enabled
- Intel VT virtualization enabled from BIOS
- Processor Cores Checked Increased - 4 Core [Max 8 Core]
- Virtualbox Version Checked

My hardware :

```
RAM Memory : 8GB
VGA Memory : 4GB
VGA        : 4GB GDDR5 nVIDIA® GeForce® GTX1050 128-Bit DX12
CPU        : Intel i5-7300HQ 4C/4T; 6MB L3; 8GT/s; 2.5GHz > 3.5GHz
```

VirtualBox Version

```
5.2.18r124319
```

Note: I cannot use dual-boot because I have to switch between operating systems fast.

I have made a fresh install to VirtualBox using the "windows 10 education default iso" from Microsoft. Is specific iso needed for VirtualBox windows 10?

Comment: could it just be the hardware

Comment: I think that this hardware pretty sufficient for running Windows 10 on the virtual machine.